# Scripted Password Change Does Not Survive Reboot Unless One Login Occurs - Debian 11

Tags: debian, bash, scripting, shell-scripting, vagrant

I am trying to automatically set the root password to random characters via bash script. The script is part of a Vagrant shell provisioner. If the script runs the password change only, I am able to login to the instance just fine. I can then reboot the instance. After the reboot, I am still able to login using that same password as root.

However, if I include a reboot at the very end of the shell provisioner script, after the reboot, login fails with that password as root.

What is happening when there is a login before the reboot that uses the new password? What else can I include in the script so that the password set is able to be used after the reboot?

Here is the Vagrant install script `install.sh`. It generates an eight character password, prints it to stdout so it can be read from the Vagrant output after `vagrant up`, and redirects it to `chpasswd`. There is no problem with this command: it works just fine if I login once before the reboot. It just gets wiped by something if the reboot is part of the script like below.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "root:$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '[:alnum:]' | fold -w ${1:-8} | head -n 1)" | tee >( chpasswd )
reboot
```

Here is the line in the `Vagrantfile` for the shell provisioner:

```ruby
config.vm.provision 'shell', path: 'install.sh'
```

Here are two diagrams:

[image: Set Root Password Automatically]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem. What is needed is a simulated login after setting the password. Nothing else is needed but the following:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
## Change Root Password
echo "root:$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc '[:alnum:]' | fold -w ${1:-8} | head -n 1)" | tee >( chpasswd )
su - root
```

This answer is based on the following:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/164890/simulate-initial-login-of-user-without-using-sudo